# how to stop snapshot in iphone programmatically?

Tags: iphone

HI all ,

I need a functionality by which i can restrict user when he is using my app he cann't take the screenshot of the application .as he exit from the app he can take snapshot in normal mode .Is there any thing by whcih we can restrict the user to stop to take the screen shot of the application.

Thanks 
Balraj

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, Apple won't let you use "hardware"-control to stop the user from the phones intended functions.

[Taptaptap](http://taptaptap.com/) wanted to use the volume-control button as a shutter to their camera app. But the app got rejected. You can read more on this issue on their blog: [Camera+ VolumeSnap: Rejected](http://taptaptap.com/blog/cameraplus-volumesnap-rejected/)

**Answer on the question**:
No, I don't think that is possible.